# How to get cookies before making request in Python

Tags: python, post, cookies, request

I am basically running my personal project,but i'm stuck in some point.I am trying to make a login request to `hulu.com` using Python's `request` module but the problem is `hulu` needs a cookie and a `CSRF` token.When I inspected the request with HTTP Debugger it shows me the action `URL` and some `request` headers.But the cookie and the `CSRF` token was already there.But how to can do that with request module? I mean getting the cookies and the `CSRF` token before the post request? Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a session then use GET and use `session.cookies.get_dict()` it will return a dict and it should have appropriate values you need

Comment: If you dont know about session start from here http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/